# Go Build remove information

Tags: go

I can already use Go Build to remove the current directory information of the project, or I can remove Gopath information, like the following, I can only delete one of them separately now

`go build -gcflags "all=-trimpath=${GOPATH}" -asmflags "all=-trimpath=${GOPATH}"`

But I don’t know how to remove them at the same time, I don’t know how to combine it

on windows, i try this

`go build -gcflags "all=-trimpath=%CD%" -asmflags "all=-trimpath=%CD%" -gcflags "all=-trimpath=%GOPATH%" -asmflags "all=-trimpath=%GOPATH%"`

It does not work

### Final Results

@ZekeLu,the answer is right.

I want to explain what happened, I expected to remove GOROOT information, but I wrote GOPATH, so I thought @ZekeLu's second answer was wrong, now I have modified and tested, there is no problem, two answers all right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this command:

```
go build -trimpath
```

Here is the doc for the `-trimpath` flag for [the Go command](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go@go1.20.5):

> -trimpath
>
> remove all file system paths from the resulting executable.
> Instead of absolute file system paths, the recorded file names
> will begin either a module path@version (when using modules),
> or a plain import path (when using the standard library, or GOPATH).

If you only want to remove some of the prefixes, you can do it like this:

```
go build -gcflags "all=-trimpath=%CD%;%GOPATH%" -asmflags "all=-trimpath=%CD%;%GOPATH%"
```

Both [the Compile command](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/compile@go1.20.5) and [the Asm command](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/asm@go1.20.5) calls `objabi.ApplyRewrites` to trim paths. According to [the implementation of objabi.ApplyRewrites](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/5b72f45dd17314af39627c2fcac0fbc099b67603/src/cmd/internal/objabi/line.go#L60-L79), The `rewrites` argument is a ;-separated list of rewrites.

```golang
// ApplyRewrites returns the filename for file in the given directory,
// as rewritten by the rewrites argument.
//
// The rewrites argument is a ;-separated list of rewrites.
// Each rewrite is of the form "prefix" or "prefix=>replace",
// where prefix must match a leading sequence of path elements
// and is either removed entirely or replaced by the replacement.
func ApplyRewrites(file, rewrites string) (string, bool) {
    start := 0
    for i := 0; i <= len(rewrites); i++ {
        if i == len(rewrites) || rewrites[i] == ';' {
            if new, ok := applyRewrite(file, rewrites[start:i]); ok {
                return new, true
            }
            start = i + 1
        }
    }

    return file, false
}
```

Comment: thank you,  i try  `go build -trimpath main.go`  , it works.
But the second one still doesn't work

Comment: @zhangpeter For the second one, can you edit your question to include a demo and show how do you check whether it works or not?

Comment: I have edited the question, I made a mistake, what should be removed is the GOROOT information